# How can I pass a Python dictionary as argument to a script via GNU Parallel?

Tags: python, bash, gnu-parallel

I am passing a valid **Python dictionary as an argument** to my Python script. This is part of a set of experiments, so my script will have to be launched multiple times and with different values in the dictionary. I am using remote machines, so I am resorting to GNU Parallel, which has served me well in the past (yes, I cited the paper :).

The thing is, arguments get manipulated repeatedly and so I need to use quotes and backslashes to make my argument arrive sound and safe. My question is: is there a better way to do this?

This is a minimal Python script:

```
import ast
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
print(ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1]))
```

If I run the following command I obtain the desired result:

```
parallel --header : python example.py '\{\"var1\":\ {var1},\ \"var2\":\ {var2}\}' ::: var1 1 ::: var2 2
```

Output:

```
{"var1": 1, "var2": 2}
{'var1': 1, 'var2': 2}
```

Is there a prettier way to spell out the dictionary?

I am very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are a good way of getting rid of some of the quoting-hell:

```
myfunc() {
  python example.py '{"var1": "'"$1"'", "var2": "'"$2"'"}'
}
export -f myfunc

parallel --header : myfunc  ::: var1 "1st var" ::: var2 "2nd var"
```

-q can also help (but limits you to have a single statement (no composed commands or redirections):

```
parallel -qv --header : python example.py '{"var1": "{var1}", "var2": "{var2}"}'  ::: var1 "1st var" ::: var2 "2nd var"
```

You do not write how tricky your input values are. If they contain " or TAB then you need additional quoting:

```
parallel --colsep '\n' -qv --header : python example.py '{"var1": "{=1 $_=Q($_) =}", "var2": "{=2 $_=Q($_) =}"}'  ::: var1 "1st\"\$#<TABHERE>var" ::: var2 "2nd var"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it to some mess at the start and end of your quoted string by doing the following:

```
parallel  --header : python /tmp/test.py "'"'{"var1": {var1}, "var2": {var2}}'"'" ::: var1 2 ::: var2 1
```

This now means that you don't have to worry about escaping the values within the dict as it ends up single quoted to whatever is actually processing it.